Merging PostGIS tables with billions of rows
I'm trying to create a unified high population density dataset using the Facebook "data for good" dataset. Currently their dataset is available as a raster or CSV per catagory (men, women, children, elderly etc) and is horribly ineffeciently stored. I'm trying to convert the dataset into something more usable, like a parquet file or compressed geopackage vector file, that I can use in other projects.
The CSV looks something like:



Lat
Lon
Population




-22.1
60.0
0.3


-22.2
60.0
0.1


-22.4
60.0
0.9



with 1 file per population class and ~150M rows per file. The rows in the files are not sorted in the same way. ;
I've inserted all these files into their own schema in Postgres+PostGIS, created a geometry column, added a spatial index to it. I now want to create a single table that has:



Geom
Child Pop
Man Pop
...
Elderly Pop




Point(lon,lat)
0.3
0.3
...
Null


Point(lon,lat)
0.1
0.5
...
Null


Point(lon,lat)
Null
1.2
...
0.3



for categories: children, youth, men, women, elderly, total, etc.
The lon/lat data is coming from a 25m grid (the same for the raster) and is mostly sparse. There are points that overlap between the tables but there are also places where there are one class but no another. There should be no cases of there being multiple identical geoms in the same table.
This SQL works for small samples:
WITH 
kids as (SELECT geom, population, 'children' as category FROM pop.children limit 100),
men as (SELECT geom, population, 'men' as category FROM pop.men limit 100),
women as (SELECT geom, population, 'women' as category FROM pop.women limit 100),
all_pop as (
        SELECT * FROM kids
        union all 
        SELECT * from men
        union all 
        SELECT * from women)

SELECT 
  geom,
  SUM(CASE WHEN category = 'children' THEN population ELSE 0 END) as child_pop,
  SUM(CASE WHEN category = 'men' THEN population ELSE 0 END) as men_pop,
  SUM(CASE WHEN category = 'women' THEN population ELSE 0 END) as women_pop
FROM all_pop
GROUP BY geom

but I'm hesitent to try it with the whole dataset. Is "group by geom" the best way to merge spatial tables where there are gridded points? Is CTE + union all + case statements the best way to join multiple tables? Can crosstab handle huge tables?
This takes about 20 seconds for 3 x 1M samples, and 72 seconds for 3 x 10M samples, 170 secs for 5 x 10M.  The analyze function is saying that it hits all the indexes and spends most of it's time in the group by aggregate.
I'm a little shocked how well my first stab at this SQL is performing, but surely this isn't the best, or even a good way of doing this?
EDIT:
I threw caution to the wind and let rip. Took just under 3 minutes to create a materialised view of all the rows, without any limits in the CTE's.
The funny thing is that the mat view has 30M rows which is clearly not right. Also the results seem to be that only a single case statement is getting populated (one column has a value while all others are 0).  PEBKAC

Don't use GEOMETRYs for preparation unless needed; the geometry column and its index each, are probably larger than the actual dataset. A multi-column index on Lat Lon is probably smaller and faster for grouping, especially with all-INT2 (Lat10, Lon10). Or GeoHash, even. Personally I'd avoid using an RDBS for ETL like a pest. Even a Python script would be better suited, especially if a flat file format is what you're after eventually. Pre-parse and spill to files tiled by a lower resolution grid scheme to then merge, if RAM is an issue - I/O would be your only bottleneck, really.

You're 100% correct. I didn't even stop to think whether postgis was the right tool for the job; "Spatial data? Straight to postgis!." Turning them into parquet files first and then using dask or something like that is probably the correct answer.


Is CTE + union all + case statements the best way to join multiple tables?

You can simplify that to just two full joins: demo at db<>fiddle
select*from pop.children 
full join   pop.men   using(lat,lon)
full join   pop.women using(lat,lon);




lat
lon
population
population
population




1
1
0.74
null
null


2
2
0.36
0.06
null


3
3
0.94
0.09
0.49


4
4
null
0.21
0.39


5
5
null
null
0.58



Which achieve the exact same thing, in a simpler and faster manner. It's clearer for the reader and equally importantly, for the built-in rewriter/planner/optimiser. It outperforms both the initial query as well as its version with geom replaced by lat,lon on 3x300k rows with no indexes here. If you add unique indexes, it speeds up further thanks to inner unique savings.
Since you're merging 3 whole tables, I don't think Postgres will be easily persuaded to use indexes for anything else than checking if a column is unique. Even if I make them so sparse they barely match anywhere, seq scans remain the preference. My bet would be that the index hits you saw could've been because you pulled small subsets using limit, which won't translate to how an unconstrained version of the query behaves.

Is "group by geom" the best way to merge spatial tables where there are gridded points?

The lat and lon you started with can establish the exact same groups costing you 8 bytes each. There's no need or benefit in involving or even constructing the 32-byte geometry for the purpose. Nothing inherently wrong with that either - Postgres can and will just hash those automatically.

Can crosstab handle huge tables?

It isn't clear why you'd want that here, but yes, although that would further complicate the query, and definitely won't be appreciated by the optimiser.

PostgreSQL supports aggregate filter clause, which means that your
SUM(CASE WHEN category = 'children' THEN population ELSE 0 END) as child_pop

emulates the native
SUM(population)FILTER(WHERE category = 'children') as child_pop


FWIW, merging ~1B rows (3x324M) to get 557M unique locations with the 3 population columns took 29min on a single core/thread/worker.
